# How can I implement a `return` URL in the email verification flow of a Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, signed-url

I'm using Laravel 7.3 with the built-in user email verification flow.

I'm trying to implement a 'return URL' into the flow, so that I can redirect a user to a specific URL after verifying their email. This is useful for when a user starts an action on the app such as subscribing. That action requires an account, and an account requires verification.

I have included the return URL within the URL at every step of the flow and I'm generating a verification URL that looks like the following:

`https://localhost/email/verify/287/23e499466a6bad538df7ce48e090294502502a86?expires=1630005974&signature=f77d57494132c71735e744a224e5116974fec33b482ec5874c40ca6321d200e6&return=https://localhost/subscribe`

So far so good. However, this returns a 403. Tracking it down leads me to:

`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php` /
`Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator`

```
public function hasCorrectSignature(Request $request, $absolute = true)
{
    $url = $absolute ? $request->url() : '/'.$request->path();

    $original = rtrim($url.'?'.Arr::query(
        Arr::except($request->query(), 'signature')
    ), '?');
            
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $original, call_user_func($this->keyResolver));
    
    return hash_equals($signature, (string) $request->query('signature', ''));
}
```

Dumping out `$original` shows me this: `https://localhost/email/verify/287/23e499466a6bad538df7ce48e090294502502a86?expires=1630005974&return=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsubscribe%2F2`

It's what I'm expecting, but the function returns `false`, which throws the 403.

I can't imagine this is an unusual use-case, but I'm struggling to find anything online about the best way to implement it.

Below is how I'm constructing the URL, this is inside my `VerifyEmail` notification. I've tried adding the `return` as a parameter of the signed route itself but it also 403s:

```
$url = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
    'verification.verify',
    Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
    [
        'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
        'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
    ]
);

// Add this here rather than as a parameter so it doesn't form part of the hash
$url = $url.'&return='.request()->get('return') ?? '';
return $url;
```

To make things more puzzling, if `return` is *empty* in the verification URL then if verifies just fine. For example this works:

`https://localhost.com/email/verify/287/23e499466a6bad538df7ce48e090294502502a86?expires=1630005974&signature=f77d57494132c71735e744a224e5116974fec33b482ec5874c40ca6321d200e6&return=`

EDIT:

After some further investigating I've worked out that adding the return URL to the signed URL generation means it works so long as `return` is not empty. If an empty string is passed then a 403 is generated when verifying.

```
$url = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
    'verification.verify',
    Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
    [
        'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
        'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
        'return' => rtrim(request()->get('return'), '/') ?? '',
    ]
);

return $url;
```

The above works fine if there is a `return` value, otherwise it 403s.